# Ignore parent padding

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get my horizontal rule to ignore the parent padding.

Here's a simple example of what I have:

```css
#parent {
  padding:10px;
  width:100px;
}
hr {
  width:100px;
}
```

You will find that the horizontal rule extends out of the parent by 10px. I'm trying to get it to ignore the padding that everything else in the parent div needs.

I'm aware that I could make a separate div for everything else; this is not the solution I'm looking for.

Answer (score 266, accepted):

Easy fix, just do

```
margin:-10px
```

on the hr.

Comment: This works, but the problem is that it won't extend the full length of the parent div. This is because the padding is NOT included in the 100px width, this means that it's actually 120px wide, and your `<hr>` will be 20px from the end of your div. See this jsFiddle for what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/YVrWy/1/

Comment: Yeah I worked that out when I added it in; the width is irrelevant.

Comment: if you need 100% width just use auto as width attribute. The width will be calculated with respect to the given margins.

Comment: You should do something like...   margin: 0 -15px;  .....otherwise the hr will vertically suck adjacent content towards it.

Comment: kinda hackish. wish there was a better way

Comment: @AlastairPitts this is the solution to your fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jb2xtygz/

Answer (score 63):

For image purpose you can do something like this

```css
img {
    width: calc(100% + 20px); /* twice the value of the parent's padding*/
    margin-left: -10px; /* -1 * parent's padding*/
}
```

Comment: But what if you don't necessarily know the parent's padding?

Comment: This worked for me when I use min-width, instead of just width.

Comment: @user5707327 you can always combine styles with javascript to get the parent's padding

Answer (score 16):

In large this question has been answered but in small parts by everyone. I dealt with this just a minute ago.

I wanted to have a button tray at the bottom of a panel where the panel has 30px all around. The button tray had to be flush bottom and sides.

```
.panel
{
  padding: 30px;
}

.panel > .actions
{
  margin: -30px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  padding: 30px;
  width: auto;
}
```

I did a demo [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EVYryR) with more flesh to drive the idea. However the key elements above are offset any parent padding with matching negative margins on the child. Then most critical if you want to run the child full-width then set width to auto. (as mentioned in a comment above by [schlingel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/745127/schlingel)).

Answer (score 13):

Another solution:

```
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
```

just change the top/right/bottom/left to your case.

Answer (score 7):

Kinda late.But it just takes a bit of math.

```
.content {
  margin-top: 50px;
  background: #777;
  padding: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  font-size: 11px;
  border: 1px dotted #222;
}

.bottom-content {
  background: #999;
  width: 100%; /* you need this for it to work */
  margin-left: -30px; /* will touch very left side */
  padding-right: 60px; /* will touch very right side */
}

<div class='content'>

  <p>A paragraph</p>
  <p>Another paragraph.</p>
  <p>No more content</p>


  <div class='bottom-content'>
      I want this div to ignore padding.
  </div>
```

I don't have Windows so I didn't test this in IE.

fiddle:
[fiddle example..](http://jsfiddle.net/xtzGy/)

Comment: You should split the padding-right:60px to padding-left:30px;padding-right:30px, so that the content isn't offset when you use text-align: center;

Answer (score 6):

If you have a parent container with vertical padding and you want something (e.g. an image) inside that container to ignore its vertical padding you can set a negative, but equal, margin for both 'top' and 'bottom':

```
margin-top: -100px;
margin-bottom: -100px;
```

The actual value doesn't appear to matter much. Haven't tried this for horizontal paddings.

Answer (score 5):

```
margin: 0 -10px;
```

is better than

```
margin: -10px;
```

The later sucks content vertically into it.

Answer (score 4):

Here is another way to do it.

```
<style>
    .padded-element{margin: 0px; padding: 10px;}
    .padded-element img{margin-left: -10px; width: calc(100% + 10px + 10px);}
</style>
<p class="padded-element">
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/3014019/pexels-photo-3014019.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940">
</p>
```

Here are some examples on repl.it: https://repl.it/@bryku/LightgrayBleakIntercept

Answer (score 2):

Your parent is 120px wide - that is 100 width + 20 padding on each side so you need to make your line 120px wide. Here's the code. Next time note that padding adds up to element width.

```
#parent
{
    width: 100px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: Red;
}

hr
{
    width: 120px;
    margin:0 -10px;
    position:relative;
}
```

Comment: With defined width is easy. Problem is when you do not know width

Comment: @GuilhermeFerreira Use `width: auto;` in `hr`. http://jsfiddle.net/ToolmakerSteve/7p85dsrq/3/  Unfortunately, this solution still requires knowing `padding` set by parent.

Answer (score 2):

If your after a way for the hr to go straight from the left side of a screen to the right this is the code to use to ensure the view width isn't effected.

```
hr {
position: absolute;
left: 0;
right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem could come down to which box model you're using. Are you using IE?

When IE is in quirks mode, `width` is the outer width of your box, which means the padding will be inside. So the total area left inside the box is `100px - 2 * 10px = 80px` in which case your 100px wide `<hr>` will not look right.

If you're in standards mode, `width` is the inner width of your box, and padding is added outside. So the total width of the box is `100px + 2 * 10px = 120px` leaving exactly 100px inside the box for your `<hr>`.

To solve it, either adjust your CSS values for IE. (Check in Firefox to see if it looks okay there). Or even better, set a document type to kick the browser into strict mode - where also IE follows the standard box model.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
 ...
```

http://www.quirksmode.org/css/quirksmode.html

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add negative margins to the child that match the padding of the parent. No need to set a width, change the box-sizing, or use absolute positioning.

```
#parent {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100px;
}

hr {
  margin-right: -10px;
  margin-left: -10px;
  // For modern browsers you can use margin-inline: -10px
}
```

The reason you don't need to set a width is because the hr element is a block element. It's width defaults to "auto", which means it will expand to fill it's parent (minus padding, margin, and border).

Answer (score -2):

easy fix.. add to parent div:

box-sizing: border-box;

Comment: This won't fix the issue. The only change it would make is make the width of the #parent element narrower.