# Make img ignore parent padding and sit flush to container edges with negative margin while being responsive

Tags: html, css

**I have a parent div with padding, but I want certain child elements to ignore the padding and sit flush to the container but still be responsive**

Things need to be to avoided:

- Adding extra padding div only around children to have padding
- Targeting children separately i.e. `.group p, .group li, .group ul, {padding:2vw;}`
- Hide any significant part of the image (10px is fine)
- Image positioning being inconsistent **(should stay centered)**

Using negative margins and `overflow:hidden` on parent div works, but the results are inconsistent as can be seen by making the snippet full screen on desktop.

#### Example:###

```css
.group {
  max-width: 700px;
  background: #bf0b30;
  padding: 4vh 3vw;
  color: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.group img {
  width: 110%;
  margin: -4vh -3vw 5vh;
  max-height:200px;
  padding: 0;
}

figure {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<!-- has padding -->
<div class="group">
  <!-- ignore padding -->
  <figure class="figure">
    <!-- ignore padding -->
    <img class="image" src="https://source.unsplash.com/random" />
  </figure>
  <h2>My Title</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
  <ul>
    <li>Sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt</li>
    <li>ut labore et dolore magna aliqua</li>
  </ul>
  <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam</p>
  <p>quis nostrud exercitation</p>
</div>
```

**This is different to suggested answer:**
[Ignore parent padding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4296530/ignore-parent-padding)
Because the answers are using 10 year old CSS unable to address specific issues I'm asking about.

Comment: Your right about the short hand, I never seen it written like that that, but I looked it up even before  reading your comment. However you do need to adjust your image. Furthermore the standard way to ignore padding is -margin, like you are doing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ignore parent padding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4296530/ignore-parent-padding)

Comment: Thanks adjust the image in what way? No that not what I was after, thanks though

Comment: My sample code was already using negative margin, my question was more about getting the image to fit to the edge and still be responsive without sacrificing parts of the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Soon after finishing writing the question I realised the answer.

I had to make the width use a **calc** function

Then add double the negative margin amount to the 100% width.

i.e. as the negative margin is 3vw each side I used `width: calc(100% + 6vw);`

#### Snippet:###

```css
.group {
  max-width: 700px;
  background: #bf0b30;
  padding: 4vh 3vw;
  color: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.group img {
  width: calc(100% + 6vw);
  margin: -4vh -3vw 5vh;
  max-height:200px;
  padding: 0;
}

figure {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<!-- has padding -->
<div class="group">
  <!-- ignore padding -->
  <figure class="figure">
    <!-- ignore padding -->
    <img class="image" src="https://source.unsplash.com/random" />
  </figure>
  <h2>My Title</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
  <ul>
    <li>Sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt</li>
    <li>ut labore et dolore magna aliqua</li>
  </ul>
  <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam</p>
  <p>quis nostrud exercitation</p>
</div>
```